# How do I use have a constructor with another class object in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I've got a simple program where I have two classes which are `Hat` and `Person`. Each `Person` has a `string name`, a `int idNum` and a hat object. Each hat simply has a string of `hatType` and a char of `hatSize`. In the main method I want to simply declare 2 people and use a display method to show the information. Here's my current code, please go easy on me I'm still new to *OOP* in c++.

**Person Class**

```
class Person
{
  private:
    string name;
    unsigned int idNum;
    Hat myHat;

  public:
    Person(string, unsigned int, Hat);
    void display();
};


Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID)
{
    name = personName;
    idNum = personID;
    myHat = hat;
}

void Person::display()
{
        cout << "Given name : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Id. number : " << idNum << endl;
        hat.display();
}
```

**Hat Class**

```
class Hat
{
  private:
    string hatType;
    char hatSize; // S, M, L

  public:
    Hat(string,char);
    void display();
};

Hat::Hat(string _type, char _size){
    hatType = _type;
    hatSize = _size;
}

void Hat::display()
{
    cout << "Hat type   : " << hatType << endl;
    cout << "Hat size   : " << hatSize << endl;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{

    Person personA("Alice",12321, Hat("Trilbee",'M'));

    Person personB("Bob",2324, Hat("Ferret",'S'));

    personA.display();
    personB.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing the hat in the Person constructor : `Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID)`

Comment: Add Hat to constructor : Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID, const Hat& hat)

Comment: When I add Hat hat I get this error: no matching function for call to 'Hat::Hat()' @Cid

Comment: another thing: for these easy inits it's better to use a member initializer list https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the complete corrected(working) version. I have added some comments to show the changes i made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Hat
{
  private:
    string hatType;
    char hatSize; // S, M, L

  public:
    Hat(string,char);
    //Added this default constructor since it won't be synthesized automatically
    Hat()
    {
        std::cout<<"Default constructor"<<std::endl;
    }
    void display();
};

Hat::Hat(string _type, char _size){
    hatType = _type;
    hatSize = _size;
}

void Hat::display()
{
    cout << "Hat type   : " << hatType << endl;
    cout << "Hat size   : " << hatSize << endl;
}
class Person
{
  private:
    string name;
    unsigned int idNum;
    Hat myHat;

  public:
    Person(string, unsigned int, Hat);
    void display();
};

//added the 3rd parameter of type Hat
Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID, Hat hat)
{
    name = personName;
    idNum = personID;
    myHat = hat;
}

void Person::display()
{
        cout << "Given name : " << name << endl;
        cout << "Id. number : " << idNum << endl;
        myHat.display();//changed hat.display() to myHat.display();
}

int main()
{
    Person personA("Alice",12321, Hat("Trilbee",'M'));

    Person personB("Bob",2324, Hat("Ferret",'S'));

    personA.display();
    personB.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back to you. This is fantastic thanks so much for providing this I now understand it perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

your Person class here:

```
 Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID) 
 {
  . ...
```

is not fully implemented just add the **hat** parameter...

```
Person::Person(string personName, unsigned int personID, Hat hat)
{....
```

Comment: This will make an unnecessary copy of the Hat object. So better use const Hat&, the const is there because the constructor must not change the content of hat.

Comment: Yeah I just spotted this. Even when I do add that I get an error saying 'no matching function for call to 'Hat::Hat()'. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DamonO'Neil - Because your constructors are not doing initialization, they are doing assignment. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/926752/817643

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica how do I initialise it in this context?

Comment: @DamonO'Neil - You read the link I provided, with its many examples.